# Do we need to use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode for Resources to prevent XSS?

Tags: c#, security, encoding, xss

We need to use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode on our website. Do we need to use it for Resources? Is there any potential threat?

```
<%=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Resources.MyResourceString)%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your resources come from a known-safe source (which I suspect they do), then you don't need to do that, no.

Comment: Please also see Yuliy's answer; it is actually better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

If your resources are HTML, then don't reencode them. If they're text, then HtmlEncode them.

If your resources are just plain old text (i.e. could contain raw ampersands or angle brackets), then even if you don't open up an XSS hole, you *still* need to HtmlEncode them so that you'll generate valid HTML.

Comment: This is actually a better answer than mine; I'm sort of disappointed in myself for not noting that; `HtmlEncode` isn't necessarily about security at its root - it's about properly encoding text so that it shows up 'literally' in the output. If the resources are supposed to be 'literal text', they should be encoded when output.

Answer (score 0):

Not to prevent cross-site scripting - that is, unless your users have access to the resources for your application and can insert something malicious!